# MongoDB Upgrade to 3.0: HostAndPort Exception

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I want to upgrade my small MongoDB-Cluster (1 mongos, 3 config-servers, 2 shards a 3 nodes) running on OpenSuSe 13.1 (64bit) from 2.6.7 to 3.0.5. But it fails at the [second step](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#upgrade-the-cluster-s-meta-data) of the upgrade guide: upgrade a mongos instance

What I'm done:

- downloaded a legacy-linux-64bit-version of MongoDB 3.0.5
- deactivated load balancer
- tried to start mongos with

  mongos --configdb data/configdb --config config/router.conf --upgrade

This is the output of mongos:

```
2015-08-07T15:41:43.281+0200 W SHARDING running with 1 config server should be done only for testing purposes and is not recommended for production
2015-08-07T15:41:43.290+0200 I SHARDING [mongosMain] MongoS version 3.0.5 starting: pid=22726 port=27027 64-bit host=myhostname (--help for usage)
2015-08-07T15:41:43.290+0200 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] db version v3.0.5
2015-08-07T15:41:43.290+0200 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] git version: 8bc4ae20708dbb493cb09338d9e7be6698e4a3a3
2015-08-07T15:41:43.290+0200 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] build info: Linux build2.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-08-07T15:41:43.290+0200 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-08-07T15:41:43.290+0200 I CONTROL  [mongosMain] options: { config: "conf/router.conf", net: { bindIp: "myhostname", port: 27027 }, security: { keyFile: "res/mongodb.key" }, sharding: { configDB: "data/configdb/" }, upgrade: true }
uncaught DBException in mongos main:
9 Empty host component parsing HostAndPort from ""
```

I'm using the same settings as the already running instance, so the network settings should be correct.

Anyone a clue what I'm doing wrong here? Why is there a warning about one config server only, while I'm using three? And what does the exception mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error/exception is because you point to a local database with --configdb. That should be a serverip:port:

```
##shards/replicas:
mongod --shardsvr --replSet ReplName --dbpath /data/mongodb (--port 27018) --logpath /data/log/log.log ...
##configservers:
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/cfg (--port 27019) --logpath /data/log/log.cfg
##mongos routers:
mongos --configdb cfg1IP:cfg1PORT,cfg2IP:cfg2PORT,cfg3IP:cfg3PORT (--port 27017) --logpath /data/log/log.mongos
```

Or you can use a configuration file.

But here you seem to mix the configuration for configservers with mongos-routers.